# How to create a list in pyspark dataframe's column

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe, which contains the following data:

```
df.show()

    +-----+------+--------+
    | id_A| idx_B| B_value|
    +-----+------+--------+
    |    a|     0|       7|
    |    b|     0|       5|
    |    b|     2|       2|
    +-----+------+--------+
```

Assuming B have total of 3 possible indices, I want to create a table that will merge all indices and values into a list (or numpy array) that looks like this:

```
final_df.show()

    +-----+----------+
    | id_A|  B_values|
    +-----+----------+
    |    a| [7, 0, 0]|
    |    b| [5, 0, 2]|
    +-----+----------+
```

I've managed to go up to this point:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

temp_df = df.withColumn('B_tuple', f.struct(df['idx_B'], df['B_value']))\
            .groupBy('id_A').agg(f.collect_list('B_tuple').alias('B_tuples'))
temp_df.show()

    +-----+-----------------+
    | id_A|         B_tuples|
    +-----+-----------------+
    |    a|         [[0, 7]]|
    |    b| [[0, 5], [2, 2]]|
    +-----+-----------------+
```

But now I can't run a proper `udf` function to turn `temp_df` into `final_df`.

Is there a simpler way to do so?

If not, what is the proper function I should use to finish the transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've found a solution,

```
def create_vector(tuples_list, size):
    my_list = [0] * size
    for x in tuples_list:
        my_list[x["idx_B"]] = x["B_value"]
    return my_list

create_vector_udf = f.udf(create_vector, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

final_df = temp_df.with_column('B_values', create_vector_udf(temp_df['B_tuples'])).select(['id_A', 'B_values'])

final_df.show()

    +-----+----------+
    | id_A|  B_values|
    +-----+----------+
    |    a| [7, 0, 0]|
    |    b| [5, 0, 2]|
    +-----+----------+
```

Comment: Nice solution. I don't have much experience with UDF's yet so this is a good example for me when they can be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the `size` of the array, you can do this without a `udf`.

Take advantage of the optional second argument to [`pivot()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot): `values`. This takes in a

> List of values that will be translated to columns in the output DataFrame

So `groupBy` the `id_A` column, and pivot the DataFrame on the `idx_B` column. Since not all indices may be present, you can pass in `range(size)` as the `values` argument.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
size = 3
df = df.groupBy("id_A").pivot("idx_B", values=range(size)).agg(f.first("B_value"))
df = df.na.fill(0)
df.show()
#+----+---+---+---+
#|id_A|  0|  1|  2|
#+----+---+---+---+
#|   b|  5|  0|  2|
#|   a|  7|  0|  0|
#+----+---+---+---+
```

The indices that are not present in the data will default to `null`, so we call `na.fill(0)` as this is the default value.

Once you have your data in this format, you just need to create an array from the columns:

```python
df.select("id_A", f.array([f.col(str(i)) for i in range(size)]).alias("B_values")).show()
#+----+---------+
#|id_A| B_values|
#+----+---------+
#|   b|[5, 0, 2]|
#|   a|[7, 0, 0]|
#+----+---------+
```

Comment: Maybe, but you do get a big performance boost by specifying the values for the pivot. I'm not sure how that compares with serialization to python for the `udf`. This *may* still turn out to be better.